# Custom layout in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

i've developed an android messaging app but, i would like to change the whole layout. It even includes a alert dialog which also i want to change.. help please..

Comment: You will need to make your question much more specific if you want anyone to help with this. Provide an example layout and say what you want to change.

Comment: Have a look at this question regarding a layout and see how the question has been asked, try to do something similar relating to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096370/layout-question

Answer (score 0):

Your layout is generally in an xml file, e.g., main.xml, called with something like `setContentView(R.layout.main)`.  The main.xml file is usually in /res/layouts, and can be edited directly, independent of the Java code.

Answer (score 0):

you can define custom layout in xml files and call the layout inflator service to inflate that xml file.
If you want to customize alertdialog, then do the following
make a customized xml file and declare a view.set the setContentView method and use that xml file.
Then inflate the layout using the LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE, thenthere is a method Alertdialog.setview(view)..use that view in it.